# Scanning a txt file from a defined location to a defined location

Tags: ruby

I need to count the occurences of one string in a determinated file, I'm using

```
a = File.read(file)
```

to open the file and counting/scanning with

```
a.scan(string){cont = cont + 1}
```

but I need to count the occurrences from a defined location to a defined location of the file.. Ex: From `a[4502]` to `a[9549]`.

I don't know if I need to cut the file and after this scan, or if I can solve this using a simple loop (while, for, until, break, redo and retry), or if I can use the command

```
arq.seek(arg, IO::SEEK_SET)
```

Please, can someone help me?

Comment: [`File#read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-read) accepts an offset and a length but I am unsure if you are defining offset as lines, characters, bytes etc. e.g. `File.read(file,5047,4502)` might work for you where `4502` is the offset from the beginning of the file and `5047` (9549 - 4502) is the length to read.

Comment: Also, using  engineersmnky's suggestion, counting should be done easily with `String#count`.

Comment: I second @engineersmnky - how do you count the offset? Lines or bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the @engineersmnky suggestion

> File#read accepts an offset and a length but I am unsure if you are
>   defining offset as lines, characters, bytes etc. e.g.
>   File.read(file,5047,4502) might work for you where 4502 is the offset
>   from the beginning of the file and 5047 (9549 - 4502) is the length to
>   read

And it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the text file, add index to each line and count matches only in-between `from` and `to` line numbers (counting from zero)

```
  cont = 0
  File.open(file).each_with_index do |l,ix|
    cont += l.scan(string).count if (from..to).cover? ix
  end
```